# How to get single email size using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get Email size through Graph API.

Is there any way to get the single Email size.

Please help me out.

I am getting the Mime but I want the mail size too.

Want to try with extended property or any other way to get Email size.

Comment: What codes did you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pidtagMessageSize extended property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessagesize-canonical-property eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer 0x0E08')
```

this is the size you would see in Outlook (or other message client). Because of MimeBloat it generally won't be the exact size of the Message once its exported to a file.